# School is making us find the size of a queue without using .size() in our function

Tags: c++

I'm not sure how to find the size of a queue without using size() but our school is making us write a program and we are not allowed to use size().

Comment: Not sure if this is the spirit of the question, but you could fill it until it overflows and count the entries...

Comment: Why don't you remove elements from the queue until it is empty, and count how many you removed?

Comment: iterators might help

Comment: @sp2danny strict queues don't have iterators

Comment: Are you talking about `std::queue`? Then I don't think that is possible without modifying the queue.

Comment: Create a copy of the queue.   Count how many times it is possible to pop an element from the copy until it is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Copy to another queue and back again and count along the way.

```
int count = 0;
while (q.empty() == false) {
   q2.push(q.front());
   q.pop();
   count++;
}
while (q2.empty() == false) {
   q.push(q2.front());
   q2.pop();
}
```

Comment: A swap (or `std::move`) might be more appropriate in place of the second loop.

Comment: `push` can `move` from `front()` to avoid copies, and then you can just `q = std::move(q2)` to avoid the second half of the process.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - I agree. But since the OP implied that this is an academic exercise, I will show the more general technique rather than an optimized solution that might be harder to understand for someone new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest function `my_length(input_queue)` with a loop that pops from your input queue, pushing to a temporary queue, counting as it does so, and then pops from that temporary queue back to the input queue.